# Como corrigir o erro Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec?

Tags: java, maven

Estou com esse erro:

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ BUILD FAILURE
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 3.454s Finished at: Sat Jul 23 11:47:20 BRT 2016 Final
>   Memory: 11M/172M
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
>   (default-cli) on project csv-to-rdf: Command execution failed. Process
>   exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
>   read the following articles: [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

[image: Erro]

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Me parece bug.

Comment: Felipe, por favor edite sua pergunta com as seções relevantes do `pom.xml` e o comando que você está tentando rodar com todos os parâmetros.

Comment: E o código relevante da classe `Transformation`